# Search a collection for a sub type in C# / Linq

Tags: c#, linq, polymorphism

If I have a collection like

```
List<SomeAbstractBaseType> someList = new List<SomeAbstractBaseType>();
```

And I have added two different child types to this collection (i.e.  the two child types inherit from SomeAbstractBaseType) like this:

```
someList.Add(someChildOfType1);
someList.Add(someChildOfType2);
someList.Add(someOtherChildOfType1);
someList.Add(someOtherChildOfType2);
```

Say I want to query for all elements of someChildOfType1. How can I do this I have tried the  following (which doesn't compile, can covert from child type to parent type)

```
List<ChildType1> temp = someList.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ChildType1)).ToList();
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: I can't figure out how to reproduce your problem as your code worked for me (no compiler error). I've compiled it in .NET 3.5/4.0 and it all worked well.

Either way you can go for the `Enumerable.OfType<T>()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<ChildType1> temp = someList.OfType<ChildType1>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.OfType<T>()` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.OfType<T>()` is only available in .NET 3.5 and above so it appears that you need a solution that will work in .NET 3.0

The problem is that even though you have found all the subtypes, the list is still of the base type. One way to do build a list of subtypes is to use `ConvertAll` to cast the objects that you know are of the right type:

```
List<ChildType1> temp = someList.FindAll(x => x is ChildType1).ConvertAll(x => (ChildType1) x);
```